Conditional expectation excercise
I'm trying to solve an exercise which made me question my understanding of conditional expectation and haven't found any good resource with samples that help me clarify the concept when it comes to this type of exercise.
The exercise goes like this. Let $X$ be a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable and $Y=X^2$, find $E(X|Y)$.
My understanding of conditional expectation is a random variable that must verify:

Be measurable with regards to $\sigma(Y)$
$E(X\mathbb{1}_A)=\int_Ax dP=\int_AE(X|Y)dP=E(E(X|Y)\mathbb{1}_A)$

So I came across with the following idea:
$E(X|Y=a)=\sqrt a$     this looks like the evident option for me
I would then expect that if I take $A=[a,b]\subset [0,1]$ then:
$\int_Ax dP=\frac{x^2}{2}|^b_a=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$
and this must be the same as:
$\int_A E(X|Y)dP=\int_A \sqrt{y}dP = \int_A \sqrt{x^2}dP = \frac{x^2}{2}|^b_a=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$
so I made the replacemente of $y=x^2$ in the last integral step. The problem is that I'm not convinced about this last step and don't understand a general way to justify it maybe in a different scenario.

Since $X$ is non-negative, $X=\sqrt{Y}$, so it's already $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and in particular $\mathbb E[X|Y]=X$.
Your intuition makes sense but is not formal. Notice also that the sets $\{Y=a\}$ have measure zero, so the conditional expectation is not well-defined.

Is it nos supposed that conditional expectation $E(X|Y)$ be a function of $Y$ not $X$? How could be a good way to make that intuition formal? In order to make the last replacement more formal I guess I could say that if $w$ is in the $\sigma-$algebra that event would give $y=x^2$ that replacing it by $\sqrt{x^2}$ would end up giving $x$ as you mentioned and it is the same as the last replacement I did.

Even though I just toyed with a zero measure set the relation should be valid for any $A$ in the $\sigma-$algebra so I would expect to be valid in the integral I wrote with $A=[a,b]$.

@user1880062 it is very crucial that in OP you assumed the nonnegativity of $X,.$ I recommend to think that problem through without that assumption. Finnally note that this answer already gives you the conditional expectation as the square root of $Y,.$
